# Laravel failing to update column with decimal type

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have the following code in a controller file

```
        $customer->update([
            'name' => $request->input('name'),
            'address' => $request->input('address'),
            'phone' => $request->input('phone'),
            'percentage' => $request->input('percentage')
        ]);
```

which successfully updates everything except the percentage field which is of type DECIMAL(2,2)
I get no error messages but in my table the percentage value stays the same. I have tried replacing with a hardcoded decimal value to no avail either.

Comment: Have you added `percentage` to model `$fillable`?

Comment: there could be an issue with the data being passed to the field. make sure:
-- percentage input value is a valid decimal | -- percentage field is not being set to NULL | -- field is not protected by a "guarded" attribute in the model | -- any database triggers or constraints that might be preventing the update(a trigger that updates another table based on changes to the current table)

Comment: Why is this tagged with Javascript and vue.js, but does not contain any such code? Is this even a JS problem?

Comment: Try these: 1. Try to update percentage with your data directly in database(check for triggers). 2. Make sure you've added percentage to $fillable in your customer model(not fillable attributes wont update)  3. did you printed the value of $request->all() using dd or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be forget to add `percentage` field to fillable in model.

Check your model.

```
protected $fillable = ['your other fields','percentage'];
```

hope this work for you.

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have allocated the value size in the column and check if it matches your updated value size